# Excel: Vlookup copy and paste VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro button in excel using VBA that will perform a `Vlookup` to copy values from a number of columns and rows in my worksheet to a different place in the worksheet using the `name` column. The reason I am copying these cells is because the below cells are showing these numbers as formulas. But I want to copy them as values.

If you have any questions please ask. Thanks in advance for the help.

I have provided an example worksheet and expected result below.

I have one worksheet that looks like this:

```
name:    area:    num1: num2: num3:
test2    loc2 
test     loc1
...       ...



name:    area:    num1: num2: num3:
test     loc1      4     5     12
test2    loc2      12    65    120 
...       ...
```

Expected Result:

```
name:    area:    num1: num2: num3:
test2     loc2      12    65    120
test1    loc1      4      5    12 
...       ...



name:    area:    num1: num2: num3:
test     loc1      4     5     12
test2    loc2      12    65    120 
...       ...
```

Comment: What are the bugs in your existing code?

Comment: include your minimal code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Adding your code to your question, with where you are having a problem will probably help you get an answer.